# If a theorem says "$A \iff B$" and I want to prove $A$, does it suffice to show $A \implies B$?

Tags: proof-writing

For example, if there is theorem that says: "$[x] = [y] \iff x \sim y$," and I am asked to prove $[(a,b)] = [(c,d)]$

Is it enough to show that $[(a,b)] = [(c,d)] \implies (a,b) \sim (c,d)$, because of the theorem that says "$[x] = [y] \iff x \sim y$?"

Is it valid to assume $[(a,b)] = [(c,d)]$ and prove $(a,b) \sim (c,d)$, even though $[(a,b)] = [(c,d)]$ is the thing we are trying to prove in the first place?

Comment: I suggest you rather show $B$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it isn't OK.  For instance, suppose you are considering a 2D geometric shape and $A$ is the statement "The shape is a square" and $B$ is the statement "The shape has 4 equal sides and 4 right angles." It is true that $A \iff B$.

However, if you prove that $A \implies B$, that doesn't mean you've proven $A$. All you've shown is that if your shape is a square, then it has 4 equal sides and 4 right angles.

To prove $A$ using your theorem, you want to show that $B$ is true.  In the shape example, if you were trying to prove your object was a square, you would prove that your object had 4 equal sides and 4 right angles.

In your example, you want to show $(a,b)$~$(c,d)$. Then apply the theorem that gives you [(a,b)]=[(c,d)].